# How to dynamically generate .txt file(Notepad file)

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="Traning.dynamicnotpadxaml"
x:Name="Window"
Title="dynamicnotpadxaml"
Width="346" Height="303">

<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="14,32,10,8">
    <Label x:Name="lbl_fname" Content="First Name" Height="34" Width="87" Canvas.Left="13" Canvas.Top="21"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_fname" Height="34" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Chandra" Width="93" Canvas.Left="203" Canvas.Top="21"/>
    <Label x:Name="lbl_lname" Content="Last Name" Height="34" Width="87" Canvas.Left="13" Canvas.Top="59"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_lname" Height="34" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Sekaran" Width="93" Canvas.Left="203" Canvas.Top="59"/>
    <Label x:Name="lbl_age" Content="Age" Width="87" Height="34" Canvas.Left="13" Canvas.Top="97"/>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="22" Width="93" Height="34" Canvas.Left="203" Canvas.Top="97"/>
    <Button Content="Save" Height="40" Canvas.Left="98" Canvas.Top="178" Width="112"/>
</Canvas>
```

it's output like this

[image]

If i click the Save button the above details should be save as text document file (.txt) like below figure.i have to save this file in my local disk d:\Mydetails\notebook.txt. what should i do for that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look here: http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx

You need to give a name to the Age TextBox though, since you did not name it in your example.
And you need to wire up the Save Buttons Click event handler and copy the following code into it  (just do a double click in design view and it will take you to the event handler method automatically).

Example would be:

```
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\Mydetails\notebook.txt"))
        {
           // write a line of text to the file, you need to access your TextBox Values here
           tw.WriteLine("First Name : " + txt_fname.Text); 
           tw.WriteLine("Last Name : " + txt_lname.Text); 
           tw.WriteLine("Age : " + txt_age.Text); 
        }
```

Comment: You should always use 'using' block for the objects implementing IDisposable and then you don't need to manually close them. See the changed code.